# SQL - Using Group_Concat in With statement

Tags: sql, impala

First time caller long time listener...

I'm using HUE SQL to get information out of a database. I have a number of different data tables and attempting to write a query to get what I need out of it.

I can get a output that looks like this....

| A.Date | A.Masterref | B.Sub_referenc | C.Number | C.Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22/09/2021 | QWERTY | 1 | 10000000 | A |
| 22/09/2021 | QWERTY | 1 | 09 | B |
| 22/09/2021 | QWERTY | 1 | 4999 | C |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Where A./B./C. are different tables.

What I want..

| A.Date | A.Masterref | B.Sub reference | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22/09/2021 | QWERTY | 1 | 1000000009 |

I'm think that I need to set up a with statement at the beginning of the query.

My attempt

WITH Number AS (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(C.Number)

Then inner joins as needed

WHERE C.type IN ('A', 'B')

GROUP BY A.Master_reference)

SELECT

A.Date,

A.Master_reference,

B.Sub_Reference,

Number

What I get is

AnalysisException: Could not resolve column/field reference: Number

I also don't know how to make sure that C.Type A comes before C.Type B when concatanated?

Can anyone advise?

Thanks in advance - hopefully this all makes rough sense.

H

Comment: Hue is a GUI interface.  What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.  Your sample code is missing columns between column names, so it is not syntactically correcxt.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I've added commas into the sample code (not sure where they went) and tagged the Impala  which I think is the database which I'm using.